# How to make a (literal) "\C" as a regress?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use `String.replaceAll(regex, repl)` and make regex the literal "\C" (not an escape sequence), but `"\\C"` returns a regex error, `"\\\\C"` creates "\\C", and `"\\\C"` makes it try to make an escape sequence.  What am I suppost to do?

Edit: here's the error I get:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 1
\C
 ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.escape(Pattern.java:2177)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.atom(Pattern.java:1952)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1834)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1460)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1133)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
    at <My Class>.<My Function>(<My Class>.java:<Line>)
```

ect.

EDIT: I found my biggest problem involved returning the original string accidentally :P.  I have it working now :)

Answer (score 6):

`\\\\C` is the correct regex in java to match the string `\C`.

```
"foo bar \C".replaceAll( "\\\\C", "cc" );
// -> "foo bar cc"
```

These are the rules:

- in Java you have to escape `\` by `\\`
- `\C` means `C escaped` (it doesn't matter if C has a special meaning and really needs escaping)
- So if you want to match a string `"\C"` the normal regex is `\\C` but because of the first rule it gets `\\\\C` in Java.

Comment: actually, the problem seems to be more rooted than I thought.  That probably does work :P

Comment: @LRFLEW must be some kind of typo. please edit your question and add a copy&paste of your regex.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`String.replace("\\C", repl)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) if you don't want regex

Comment: I really should have seen this :P.  Tell me though why `str.replace("\\C", repl)` doesn't work when the string is the literal of "\CBlah"?

Comment: This has nothing to do with regex, but with plain Java escape sequences. \ gives special meaning to the next character and a \C does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, "\C" works in my regex tester which is supposed to follow the Java syntax:

```
Pattern:
\\C

Text:
This is \C a test

Replace:
sad

Result:
This is sad a test
```

Comment: e.g. this [regex tester](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html) for java accepts "normal" regex as input and generates an output with "original regex" and "Java String regex"

Comment: I guess that means your regex tester is broken.  If you look at the javadoc for the Pattern class, you won't see a "\C" listed as a recognized escape.  And it says *"It is an error to use a backslash prior to any alphabetic character that does not denote an escaped construct; these are reserved for future extensions to the regular-expression language."*.